# Codeigniter - foreach form input table

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have a foreach loop contained within a form there an input is required. I want to submit these all of input values to the database. Currently it only submits the last entry. I have tried a few different things like name="[]", Im not sure whether my issue lies in the view page or the values being picked up in the controller.

This is my view:

```
<form method="post" id="add_entry" name="add_entry" action="<?= base_url() ?>/WebAppController/add_test_batch">
                  
    <table id="example1" class="display text-center mt-5">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Phase</th>
                <th>Ingredient</th>
                <th>Instructions</th>
                <th>%</th>
                <th>Amount (g)</th>
                <th>Actual (g)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($batch as $batch){?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $batch->f_ingredients_phase?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $batch->ingredient_name?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $batch->f_ingredients_instructions?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $batch->f_ingredients_qty?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php

                            $first_number = $batch->f_ingredients_qty;
                            $second_number = $batch->product_qty;
                            $third_number = 100;

                            $sum_total = $second_number * $first_number / $third_number;

                            print ($sum_total);

                        ?> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $batch->product_id?>" name="production_batch_production[]" value="<?php echo $batch->product_id?>">
                        <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $batch->ingredient_id?>" name="production_batch_ingredients[]" value="<?php echo $batch->ingredient_id?>">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="production_batch_qty" name="production_batch_qty[]" placeholder="Enter Actual Qty">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="container text-center mt-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success mt-3 col-2">Product Produced</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my Controller:

```
 public function add_test_batch() {
                $alltestbatch = new RdProduction_BatchModel();
                $data = [
                    'production_batch_qty' => $this->request->getVar('production_batch_qty'),
                    'production_batch_production'  => $this->request->getVar('production_batch_production'),
                    'production_batch_ingredients' => $this->request->getVar('production_batch_ingredients'),
                ];

                $alltestbatch->insert($data);
                return redirect()->back();
            }
```

var_dump produces the following:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(4) "2500" [1]=> string(4) "1250" [2]=> string(4) "1000" [3]=> string(3) "250" } array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "6" [1]=> string(1) "6" [2]=> string(1) "6" [3]=> string(1) "6" } array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "4" [2]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "3" }
```

Using the die; I get an Array, stdClass Object, see below. Is then when I need to use " for($i=0;$i " as ive seen it alot in answers to similar questions?

```
Array([0] => stdClass Object(
        [product_id] => 6
        ....
        [plan_status] => New)

[1] => stdClass Object
```

Comment: Could you please `var_dump` here your `$this->request->getVar`?

Comment: @Dmitry - var_dump has been included

Comment: change `$batch as $batch`to `$batch as $b` and consequent all `$batch` in the loop to `$b`. why? because you are overwriting the original `$batch`

Comment: @vickel. When i do this I then get an error

Trying to get property 'product_id' of non-object. This is related to the hidden inputs

Comment: I'd use to check with `echo "<pre>";print_r($batch);die;` to see array structure and content (it also indicates you if it is a pure array or an array of objects)

Comment: You'd need `print_r($batch, TRUE)` if you were actually looking to output the contents of that variable rather than just return it.

Comment: @ Both, where would I be putting these?

Comment: @nate just before the foreach loop. It will stop the program due to `die();` This is just a debugging technique for you to see the array structure and if the array has any values, or more precuisly the values you are expecting, like `product_id`. After you got your read of it, just comment it out again with `//` or `#`

Comment: @Vickel, updated the above.

Comment: well then `<?php echo $b->product_id?>` should display correctly? That if you have changed to `foreach($batch as $b)`

Comment: @vickel, i have sorted the issue but it still only added the last row to the database?